# raspberry pi with 4k screen @1080p resulotion

Tags: hdmi, display, 1080p

I'd like to use 4k screen with RPi. I know that RPi can't handle 4k resolution so that is why I'd like to set resolution to 1080p. Screen will be playing videos/images (both prepared at 1080p) and my question is will it keep quality at non-native resolution? Will be there a difference between displaying on native 1080p screen?

Comment: depends on the quality of the screens upscaling 1080p to 4K

Comment: This is really a question about the (unspecified) TV screen, not about the RPi. Also "quality" is subjective unless you specify criteria to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to run Raspbian Rpi4  on Samsung 50ru7100.

After switching resolution in Raspbian the image displays on the TV but edges of desktop are off-screen.

I'll keep digging around see if I can resolve this.

Comment: FYI, a relevant setting to fix the gap at the edges of the display is called *overscan*.

Comment: Thanks. Just having a look. In the config files now.

Comment: If i boot at 1080p the overscan affects the screen size. If I switch to 1080p within Raspbian the screen is fine, until rebooted.

Comment: There's a "fit to size" option on the TV which was set to Auto. This was causing the overscan. Setting to "On" fixes the issue.